# Django Javascript Ajax - Submitting form does nothing

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, forms

I have a form with which I would like to send data to my backend view.

```
<form class="modal-content animate" method="POST" id="make_admin">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- List users to make admin -->
    <div class="container">
        <label for="uname"><b>User: </b></label>
        <select id="select_user">
            {% for employee in users %}
                {% if not employee.is_admin %}
                    <option value="{{ employee.id }}">{{ employee.first_name }} {{ employee.last_name }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <button type="submit">Make Admin</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#make_admin' ,function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'{% url 'cerberus_mvp:make_admin' %}',
    data:{
        id: $('#select_user').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        action: 'post'
    },
    success:function(response){
        $(".update").html(response)
    },
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
}
});
});
```

My problem is that when the submit button is clicked nothing happens, the page just seems to refresh. It seems like the javascript code is never reached. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Edit: If i add `window.alert("hello");` to the javascript code doesnt get to it. Think the error is with the html or `$(document).on('submit', '#make_admin' ,function(e){` line.

Comment: does form exist in moment when you are trying to attach event?
In other words document.getElementById('make_admin')

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Does adding `return false;` at the end of the submit handler help?

Comment: Do you have an element with class `update`? You're not getting an error message in the console?

Comment: To answer the questions: Browser is chrome, there is an element "update", its an empty div to display something like "Success", there is no error message.

Comment: does your browser console shows any error ?

Comment: No error message in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the click on document, which have no submit action.

select the form element not document element.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('form').on('submit', '#make_admin' ,function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
method:'POST',
url:'{% url 'cerberus_mvp:make_admin' %}',
data:{
    id: $('#select_user').val(),
    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
    action: 'post'
},
success:function(response){
    $(".update").html(response)
},
error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
}
});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="modal-content animate" method="POST" id="make_admin">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- List users to make admin -->
    <div class="container">
        <label for="uname"><b>User: </b></label>
        <select id="select_user">
            {% for employee in users %}
                {% if not employee.is_admin %}
                    <option value="{{ employee.id }}">{{ employee.first_name }} {{ employee.last_name }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <button type="submit">Make Admin</button>
    </div>
</form>
```